# Vue.js: no dynamic locale within javascript data function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, locale

we are using http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/api.html to implement locale and changing locale dynamically on our webpage.

but we currently face following issue.

this one is **not** working dynamically:

```
HTML: 
<b-breadcrumb :items="items"/>

Javascript:
public data() {
  return {
    items: [
        text: this.$t("COMPONENTS.ADMINISTRATION.HOME"),
        href: "/"
      ]
  }
}
```

this one is working dynamically:

```
HTML:
<p>{{$t("COMPONENTS.ADMINISTRATION.HOME")}}</p>
```

do you need any further information?

does anybody have any clever idea how to fix this upper example?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you should attach computed properties directly to your data initialization. Could you try to create a computed property called `translatedItems` instead, and pass that to the property? Something like `computed: { translatedItems() { return this.$t("COMPONENTS.ADMINISTRATION.HOME") } }`.

Comment: Correction: I don't think you should attach **reactive** properties directly to your data initialization.

Comment: I am using Typescript and tried to implement it this way: `public computed() { 
return { translatedItems: function () { return [
{
text: this.$t("COMPONENTS.ADMINISTRATION.HOME"),
href: "/"
}
] } }
}` I passed the translatedItems to the items for the breadcrumb but this way (of course) on the initial load there are no items in the breadcrumb shown and still not when the locale changes

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/119

Comment: After some random tests where I can put the computed properties (I wasn't familiar to them until now) it finally worked! I used the code you provided me in your first answer. The last link you provided did not work. This was the way I implemented it a while ago...nevermind it is now working :) - do you want to provide an official answer to my question so that i can acknowledge it? Thanks !

Comment: Ok, good. Could I add this fiddle to the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/7rb88429/ ? Would it be representative as a solution to your problem?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact way that solved my problem!